# Converting spring batch 3 reader to spring batch 4 reader config

Tags: spring-batch

Below is my Reader Config defined in Spring batch3

```
@Bean
    @Qualifier("myReader")
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<POJO> myReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}") String filename) {

        FlatFileItemReader<POJO> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<POJO>();     


        try {

            reader.setResource(new UrlResource(filename));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        }
        reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<POJO>() {{
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
                setNames(FileHeader);
                setDelimiter(",");

            }});
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<POJO>() {{
                setTargetType(POJO.class);
            }});
        }});
        return reader;
    }
```

As spring Batch 4 has added builder to make it more cleaner. 
Below is config in SpringBatch 4 .

```
@Bean
    @Qualifier("myReader")
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<POJO> myReader(
            @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}") String filename) throws MalformedURLException {

        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<POJO>().resource(new UrlResource(filename))
                .name("myReadersdfs")
                .delimited()
                .delimiter(",")
                .names(FileHeader)
                .targetType(POJO.class)
                .linesToSkip(1)
                .build();

    }
```

The Builder really makes code shorter and cleaner.

But i am not able to understand why reader **.name("")** **is mandatory** ?
and how it is going to be used ? does the name works like **Qualifier** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name(String value)` is required as it is used by the framework to generate the keys used to store state in the `ExecutionContext`.  In previous versions (and if you choose not to use the builders), configuring that attribute was optional.  The issue is that by not configuring it, collisions could occur in key naming within the `ExecutionContext`.  By requiring the name to be configured, the chance of a collision is less likely.